# How can I debug a rails console or server running with spring in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rdebug

Rubymine has support for [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) but according to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/spring.html) it doesn't apply to the console nor server, and in any event is disabled when debugging.

It is possible to use remote debugging, launching an [rdebug-ide](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide) under spring, and attaching that to RubyMine?

Comment: Why do you want to? Debugging a spring issue? Just curious.

Comment: The goal is to save memory and time, spinning up debuggable consoles and servers that trigger breakpoints in RubyMine, whether run within RubyMine or from the shell.